# Error while installing from script ZeroBraneStudio

Tags: zerobrane

When executing ZeroBraneStudioEduPack-1.70-linux.sh i get this error: `xdg-desktop-menu: No writable system menu directory found.`
It could be related to my desktop environment ? currently i'm using sway with xwayland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405800/installation-problem-xdg-desktop-menu-no-writable-system-menu-directory-found), seems to be an xdg bug. You can check if running `sudo mkdir /usr/share/desktop-directories/` before running the install command fixes the issue. I'll consider adding it to the install script if it helps.